# WordPress not working locally

Tags: server, localhost

I am attempting to get a local version of a live WP site working.
I have pulled down the entire file structure. I have a copy of the DB. After setting up locally, I get a few random issues such as:

1. Permalinks not working properly
2. Javascript error
3. Content generally not loading properly.
4. 500 errors (probably caused by the .HTACCESS)
5. This error caused by a plugin: **Warning: Parameter 1 to ace_where() expected to be a reference**

I suspect it has something do with a server setting of which I am unaware. The live server is IIS. I am running OSX with the built-in Apache.

I have many other WP installations working fine locally.
Any thoughts, comments, or suggestions are appreciated.

Here is the .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^client.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.client\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /~client/
RewriteCond /home2/client/public_html/wp-content/sitemaps%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule \.xml(\.gz)?$ /~client/wp-content/sitemaps%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /~client/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: IIS does not use .htaccess, disable your plugins and go back to default permalinks (rename your .htaccess and create a new one by swithcing permalinks back on).This question is impossible to answer and does not fit the format of WPSE very well.

Comment: Sorry for the bad question :(   but thanks for the input. The .htaccess file is generated by the installation of WP. The issue probably revolves IIS/Apache, and this ACE plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-category-excluder/

Answer (score 0):

If you're on OSX, look into [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/). It's developed with WordPress in mind and generally works without any further configuration. Just copy your files into the web root directory, set up an empty database, and install.

Comment: Sure, MAMP is great. But my WP environment works, just not with this site. I am pretty sure it has to do with an out-of-date plugin, and variances between PHP versions.

Comment: I'm sure you could get it working with the built in Apache on OSX.. but I know every site I've tried to run using the built in server has had _some_ sort of bug.